# Extending map objects

Tags: javascript, dictionary, prototype, extend

I don't know how to extend the map object with prototype and hope you can help.
I have something like this:

```
var map = {'one':1, 'two':2};
```

and I would like to have a method to check for the existence of a key:

```
if (map.containsKey('one')){...}
```

How would I extend the map object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's dangerous to modify Object.prototype**, because [it affects all objects and will usually break other libraries you may be using](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2005/06/06/22.13.54/).  In general, if you want to add methods to a dictionary-like object, you should create an object for your hash instances to inherit from, [like the Prototype Hash object](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/hash).

For this specific instance, you should really just use either `if (key in map)` or `if (map.hasOwnProperty(key))`.

Answer (score 4):

There is already an operator to test the existence of a key inside an object.

(In JavaScript, objects are implemented as maps so actually there is no real map.)

```
if( 'one' in map ) 
{
   alert(map['one']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These are not "maps" they are objects.  Building on Maurice's answer, if you want this to apply to all objects:

```
Object.prototype.containsKey = function(key) {
    return this.hasOwnProperty(key);
};
```

Comment: Or you could just use hasOwnProperty so that map.containsKey('containsKey') doesn't always return true!! :p

Comment: Noooo! Leave Object.prototype alone.

Comment: I think what Chetan wanted to tell you is that there's not much sense in renaming `hasOwnProperty()` to `containsKey()`, and that your solution might break code which uses `in` where it should use `hasOwnProperty()`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to add a function directly in the object:

```
map.containsKey = function(key) {
    return this[key] ? true : false;
};
```

Comment: nice, it works for now. How do I generalize it to work if I have several instances of maps?

Comment: @Haoest: Since you are using regular Javascript object as a map,  Object already has the function hasOwnProperty.

Comment: this doesn't check for a property's existance, but it's value in boolean contexts; also, it's somewhat ugly: use `return Boolean(this[key])` or `return !!this[key]` to cast to boolean

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you do not need such method really.

```
if ( map['one'] ) {
   // do something
}
```

should do it

Comment: Except when 'one' is defined and is falsy. Or if 'one' is derived from the object's prototype and not really it's own property.

Answer (score 0):

As other's have said, extending `Object.prototype` might not be a good idea if your code has to play nice with code written by people ignorant of `hasOwnProperty()`.

Anyway, there are three 'correct' ways I know of to check if a property is available:

```
obj.hasOwnProperty(name)
```

checks if a property with given name exists in the object.

```
name in obj
```

additionally includes properties inherited via an object's prototype chain.

```
typeof obj[name] !== 'undefined'
```

will additionally evaluate to `false` if the property is present but has been set to `undefined`.

Some non-JS object's (e.g. `window.external` in IE) might not implement `hasOwnProperty()`, so one of the other checks has to be used.